# SpriteKit shaders on iOS 16 - Y-axis is inverted

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, glsl, metal

My SpriteKit app, which uses several GLSL fragment shaders, is showing different shader behaviour on iOS 16 as compared to iOS 15 and earlier. On iOS 15 the y-axis increased in the direction of the bottom of the screen, but now suddenly iOS 16 appears to have inverted this and now the y-axis is increasing in the direction of the top of the screen.

The fact that this change is occurring only in my fragment shaders while SpriteKit node positioning remains unchanged between iOS 15 and 16 leads me to believe that this might be a change made in Metal 3.

Is there an elegant solution to achieving consistent behaviour between iOS versions here? I would prefer not to have to detect the user's iOS version and supply a shader uniform to invert the y-axis manually, on a per-shader basis.

Comment: I'm getting this as well with CIFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 9.15.2022

Based on the comments, it looks like this is indeed a bug (95579020) and an Apple Engineer confirmed that a fix has been identified (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713945).

However, the `SKShader` issue doesn't seem to happen when building on an Apple silicon laptop with Xcode 14.0. Not sure about the `CIFilter` issue.

### Original

Are you using `v_tex_coord`? I have tested this and it doesn't look like there's a problem between iOS 15 and iOS 16, using `v_tex_coord`. There must be something else.

*Note: I have tested this on the iOS 16.0 simulator, not on a real device.*

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshader/creating_a_custom_fragment_shader) also still mentions the bottom-left corner:

> `vec2 v_tex_coord; Varying` The coordinates used to access the texture. These coordinates are normalized so that the point (0.0,0.0) is in the bottom-left corner of the texture.

The results are the same on both iOS versions using the SKShader code below and `v_tex_coord.y`:

```
void main() {
    vec3 red = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec3 blue = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 col = mix(red, blue, v_tex_coord.y);
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

iOS 15.0 ->
[image: Yaxis_Shader]
            iOS 16.0 ->
[image: Yaxis_Shader]

Comment: Yes I am using v_tex_coord. Substituting your shader in for mine yields a blue-to-red, top-to-bottom gradient on the iOS 15.4 simulator (the same result that you have) but it is inverted on the iOS 16 simulator where it displays a red-to-blue, top-to-bottom gradient.

Comment: This is strange. I cannot replicate the problem on the simulator running iOS 16.0. I am using Xcode 14.0.

Comment: Indeed. I am using an Intel Mac so perhaps it could be different on x86 vs ARM simulators, though I am also experiencing the inversion on an actual device running iOS 16 as well. In any case, an Apple engineer has confirmed on the developer forums that this is indeed a bug and they have a fix upcoming.

Comment: Could you post the link to the forum post, for reference? If you're using Xcode 14.0, then it must be the ARM vs x86 architecture, that is the only thing that seems to be different, since you also see this problem on the simulator. I am on ARM arch.

Comment: I think I found it and I updated the answer.

Comment: It's really strange that this would be influenced by the architecture of the machine building the project since, to my knowledge, the shaders are compiled at runtime on the target device/simulator. And as mentioned, it is happening for me on an iOS 16 device which is, of course, an ARM device.

Comment: It is indeed very strange, but I have tested this very carefully and I can confirm it is working fine for me, with the provided shader. I do not have access to a real device, so can only test on simulator. The only thing I can think of is maybe Xcode changes the `v_tex_coord` at build time, on ARM arch.

Comment: Also I don't think it's a shader compilation issue, I think it's how the coordinates get normalized in the `v_tex_coord`, outside of the shader itself.

Comment: Not that this thread really needs to continue, but just to note: I built the project on an M1 mac and still had the same issue. So it's really not clear what in your environment is enabling correct results.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I really don't know why I am seeing correct results, I have used multiple shaders now, running on both iOS 16 simulator and iOS 15 device and no problems. I will update if I discover something new.