# CIMotionBlur broken in iOS16?

Tags: sprite-kit, core-graphics, core-image, ios16

The following code just does not behaves the same way previous to iOS 16 and with iOS 16. The blur effect does not seem to work correctly in iOS 16.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    
        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 30)
        shapeNode.fillColor = .green
        shapeNode.strokeColor = .clear
        addChild(shapeNode)

        let blurredShapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 30)
        blurredShapeNode.fillColor = .red
        blurredShapeNode.strokeColor = .clear
    
        let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
        addChild(effectNode)
        effectNode.addChild(blurredShapeNode)
    
        let blurAngle = NSNumber(value: 0)
        effectNode.filter = CIFilter(
        name: "CIMotionBlur", parameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: 30, kCIInputAngleKey: blurAngle])
    }
}
```

iOS < 16 looks like :

[image: iOS 15.5]

And iOS 16 looks bad (blur is shifted and stretched)

[image: iOS 16 the blur effect is shifted and stretched]

Comment: Same here with CIFilter CIGaussianBlur, it will offset it and shrink it (depending on how big the inputRadius is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been fixed by Apple in 16.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this on iOS 16.1 beta 3?

It might be related to this [SpriteKit shaders on iOS 16 - Y-axis is inverted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73710242/spritekit-shaders-on-ios-16-y-axis-is-inverted/73721648) which has been fixed in the beta.